# Why mousemove event execute out of sprite's area in PIXI JS?

Tags: pixi.js

I started to learn `pixi js` and here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ChicagoJostik/pen/oNLaarQ),

I have a sprite for which I want to call mousemove event,

and it is working, you can see it in `console.log`, but not only for the sprite, it is also working outside of the sprite.

**Here is my code:**

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let _w = wrapper.offsetWidth,
    _h = wrapper.offsetHeight,
    sprite;

const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: _w,
    height: _h,
        backgroundColor: 0x000000,
    autoResize: true, 
});

wrapper.appendChild(app.view);

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

function resize() {
  _w = wrapper.offsetWidth,
  _h = wrapper.offsetHeight;
  
  app.renderer.resize(_w, _h);
  setup();
}

const container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);

const loader = PIXI.Loader.shared; // PixiJS exposes a premade instance for you to use.
loader.add('bg','https://i.ibb.co/1T06dL6/bg.jpg').load(setup);

function setup() {
  let texture = loader.resources.bg.texture;
  sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
  const scale = Math.max( _w / sprite.texture.width, _h / sprite.texture.height);
  sprite.scale.set(scale,scale);
  sprite.x = Math.round( ( _w - sprite.width ) / 2);
  sprite.y = Math.round( ( _h - sprite.height ) / 2);
  container.addChild(sprite);
  
  sprite.interactive = true;
  sprite.buttonMode = true;
  sprite.on('mousemove', function() {
    console.log('fire');
  })
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I target only sprite area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: (is your code with some modification) https://codepen.io/domis86/pen/JjKeyzK

key points:

- `var interactionManager = app.renderer.plugins.interaction;`
- make sprite smaller (if it fits whole canvas area then will always hit) :

```
  sprite.width = 200;
  sprite.height = 200;
```

- use `interactionManager` to detect hit:

```
  sprite.on('mousemove', function(interactionData) {
      //console.log('fire');
      if(interactionManager.hitTest(interactionData.data.global, this)) {  
          console.log("mousemove over sprite");  
      }
  })
```

Docs:

- https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.InteractionManager.html#hitTest
- https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/10606-mousemove-on-sprites/